# c++ object member referential integrity: reference vs pointer and valgrind inconsistency

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, valgrind

Suppose I want to create an object that refers to an object *a* of some other class, *A*.

**Reference vs Pointer**

I know that *a* should persist for the lifespan of my new object, so my preferred approach might be to refer to *a* using a reference in the new object, passing it in upon construction.

But alternatively, one might choose to represent *a* as a pointer in the new object. This is a bit more flexible, but loses something about the relationship that's explicit with a reference.

In the following code, class *R* refers to *A* using a reference, while class *P* uses a pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
  int val; // A toy class that stores an int!                                                                                                                
public:
  A(int val_) : val(val_){}
  ~A(){}
  void dump() const { std::cout << val << std::endl; }
};

class R
{ 
  const A & a; // Represent the association with 'a' as a reference                                                                                          
public:
  R(const A & a_) : a(a_){}
  ~R(){}
  void dump() const { a.dump(); }
};

class P
{ 
  const A * a; // Represent the association with 'a' as a pointer                                                                                            
public:
  P(const A * a_) : a(a_){}
  ~P(){}
  void dump() const { a->dump(); }
};

R manufactureR(int val)
{ 
  A a(val);
  R r(a);
  r.dump();
  return r; // Pull the rug out from under 'r' as 'a' drops out of scope.                                                                                    
}

P manufactureP(int val)
{ 
  A *a = new A(val);
  P p(a);
  p.dump();
  delete a; // Pull the rug out from under 'p' by deleting 'a'.                                                                                              
  return p;
}

int main()
{ 
  // Reference version: This code is dodgy, but valgrind doesn't moan                                                                                        
  R r = manufactureR(3);
  r.dump();

  // Pointer version: This code is dodgy and valgrind rightly moans                                                                                          
  P p = manufactureP(3);
  p.dump();

  return 0;
}
```

**Valgrind and catching bugs**

As hinted above, my preference is to use references for my object members when I know reference won't need changed and the referenced object will persist during my object's lifetime.

Either way, it's obviously bad if, sometime during the new object's existence, *a* is lost/destroyed as a result of a coding bug, but the new object continues to refer to it.

But what's arguably worse is being unable to detect when mistakes occur.

The code at the end creates an instance of each of *R* and *P*, then purposely sabotages them by destroying the referenced/pointed-to object.

The output I get is along these lines:

```
$./test
3
1726372352
3
0
```

What's interesting is that when something untoward occurs, and the referenced object vanishes, valgrind doesn't report an error as I would expect. It does spot the *Invalid read of size 4* in the pointer version after the *a* is freed.

If, by using references, there's risk that a bug could cause me to read dead memory inadvertantly, and valgrind can't detect it, then it's enough to make me use pointers.

**Question**

Has anyone else observed/suffered-from this inconsistency in valgrind or, as I'm very new to C++ (coming from a long career in C), am I misunderstanding something fundamental when trying to use references as object members? Perhaps the example is flawed because I'm relying on RVO in the return from *manufactureR* to, effectively, copy (without assignment) the reference in *r*.

**Details**

`CentOS 6.5; gcc version 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5) (GCC); valgrind-3.8.1`

Comment: Valgrind spots the invalid read because that is exactly what it is: invalid. Valgrind's hooks into the memory allocators and thus detection when you try and use a pointer after being deleted (the P case) will do you no good when the object being created/destroyed is a simple automatic (the R case). The invalid read is about as good as you're going to get (big time futuristic development of magic on the Valgrind authors part not withstanding). It isn't an inconsistency. There was no dynamic allocation in the R case, and as such Valgrind's hands are severely tied.